# How can I help clients to not get macro warnings?

Tags: excel, vba

I often develop Excel solutions for clients. When the clients open a macro enabled file I have created they usually get a warning and are asked whether they want to enable macros.

What are my options for making it so that my clients don't get this warning?

Comment: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/05/28/bypass-the-excel-macro-security-warning/

Comment: Or digitally sign your workbooks.